# Ajax Request not working on firefox but works on other browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$("#form").on('submit', function(e)
    {

        var form = $('form')[0];
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "Controller/function/",
            type:"POST",
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown)
            {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                alert(errorThrown);
                if(textStatus == 'timeout')
                {
                    $('#message').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Timeout.</div>');                   
                }
                jQuery("body,html").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 2000);

            },
```

I have neglected the success part cause I feel it will be of no help here.
The code works perfectly fine on mobile device and edge but does not work on firefox.
The error handler returns 'undefined' for both alerts.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get any js in borwser console? what about on the server side? do you receive the same correct data? and does your server side return the expected data back to the ajax request?

Comment: What is the textStatus ?